# Notepad++ - Remove second and third comma in a csv in one shot

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a csv file having thousands of lines of data with comma delimited, i need to remove 2nd and 3rd commas from those lines

example below

```
8213201711,77,429,890,5d810ffc6
9801201711,103,088,818,5d810ffc
8113201711,102,829,857,5d810ffb
8113201711,104,186,726,5d810ffc
8101201711,86,337,068,5d810ffb1
8205201711,77,137,917,5d72788c9
```

I need

```
8213201711,77429890,5d810ffc6
9801201711,103088818,5d810ffc
8113201711,102829857,5d810ffb
8113201711,104186726,5d810ffc
8101201711,86337068,5d810ffb1
8205201711,77137917,5d72788c9
```

I tried to find

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),(.*)$
```

and replace with

```
\1\2
```

but, its removing only 2 occurrence

Comment: You only referenced the first and the second occurrence; there is no mention of the third in your search pattern

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$
```

and

```
\1\2\3
```

Note that the 2nd and 3rd literal commas in the expression are outside parens.

EDIT: I guess it would have been simpler from a minimal edit standpoint to use `^([^,]*,[^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),`  and `\1\2`. I wasn't sure off the top of my head all of the search and replace options that I might have been overlooking so it seemed safer to work with the whole line. In hindsight that was probably silly.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d+,\d+\K,(\d+),`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
  ,         : a comma
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  ,         : a comma
  (\d+)     : group 1, 1 or more digits
  ,         : a comma
```

You may use `[^,]` instead of `\d` if you have other character than digits.

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (ie. the digits between 2nd and 3rd comma)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
8213201711,77429890,5d810ffc6
9801201711,103088818,5d810ffc
8113201711,102829857,5d810ffb
8113201711,104186726,5d810ffc
8101201711,86337068,5d810ffb1
8205201711,77137917,5d72788c9
```